# if make i changes in cpanel filemanager it doesn't really take effects on the web site

Tags: file, hosting, cpanel

so as you see from the address I make changes in the public_html folder and I see the changes through the cpanel filemanager. however, it doesn't make any changes in the website and when I try to see the files of the website through my domain I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVvZo.jpg) can see that there are no changes happened . the changes is like creating a new folder or file or even renaming a file

Answer (score 0):

This type of problems may occur due to server sided caching or it can be a simple bug which doesn't let the code to execute it on the website.

Or might be the server issues, for which you should contact the customer care of your hosting provider.

Try to clean cache of your browser and also disable the caching in your server if enabled.

Try these all things and you may see changes.